# C# - EPPlus sometimes only returning cells with values, breaking my data gathering

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

The long story short is I'm trying to convert the data from 3 different Excel documents into 5 separate CSV files, using a combination of data from all of them to do it. 2 of the 3 files are working without issues, but one of the files contains slightly different data - though there are 9 total columns being utilized (41,730 rows), only 3-5 of the columns will have data in each row other than the first (header row). The issue comes up in that it doesn't actually even include the columns without data...so throwing all of the data into an array list has varying numbers of segments in the individual arrays (so I can't associate the data properly).

Here's the code I'm running:

```
using (ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(new System.IO.FileInfo(strInputFile)))
        {
            ExcelWorksheet myWorksheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
            int totalRows = myWorksheet.Dimension.End.Row;
            int totalColumns = myWorksheet.Dimension.End.Column;

            for (int rowNum = 1; rowNum <= totalRows; rowNum++)
            {
                var row = myWorksheet.Cells[rowNum, 1, rowNum, totalColumns].Select(c => c.Value == null ? string.Empty : c.Value.ToString());
                listOutput.Add(string.Join("~", row).Split('~'));
            }
        }
```

This works perfectly for the others, but in this file the first row has 9 segments, then every subsequent row has 3-5, depending on how many columns have values (the first 2 will always have values, then 1-2 additional columns will in each row). The other files are filling in the blank columns with empty strings, using the lambda in the Select, but I don't know why it's not doing it in this one. All 3 came from the same source (client environment export), and have the same formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely `myWorksheet.Cells[rowNum, 1, rowNum, totalColumns]` simply isn't returning the cells that don't have values. Try something like this:

```
var row = Enumerable.Range(1, totalColumns)
    .Select(columnNum => myWorksheet.Cells[rowNum, columnNum])
    .Select(c => c?.Value?.ToString() ?? string.Empty);
```

Comment: That was my first guess, but not sure why it's returning the empty cells in the other 2 workbooks without issue and just not here. For now, on this iteration of the file, I just used Excel itself to add "(NoValue)" to the blank cells so I could get an initial output, but I'll try out your code in a min to see if it'll work long-term.

Comment: If you open the excel sheets' contents (unzip the .xlsx file and look at the XML files inside), I suspect you'll find there are some cells that have an entry in the XML, but their entry is blank. Then there are other cells that simply don't have an entry: they are blank implicitly, by omission.